# Como herdar métodos de um protótipo para outro usando o módulo 'util' do Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, herança

Estava vendo o vídeo de um cara explicando eventos do Node.js e no fim ele faz um pequeno módulo usando `util.inherit` para herdar de um protótipo construtor para outro. Apesar de conhecer a sintaxe do `call` e ter pego uma noção do método `util.inherit` na [API DOCS](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor), não consegui captar a semântica do código no geral.

Construtor do módulo

```
var EventEmitter - require('events').EventEmitter;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

function FireDetector(){
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

inherits(FireDetector, EventEmitter);

FireDetector.prototype.smoke = function(amount){
    if(amount > 0.5) {
        this.emit('fire').
    }
}

module.exports = FireDetector;
```

Exemplo de uso do módulo (só como bônus)

```
var FireDetector = require('./firedetector');

fireDetector = new FireDetector();

fireDetector.on('fire', function() {
    console.log('fire fire fire');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez a tua dúvida fique clarificada se deres uma olhada ao [código do Node/util no GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L615-L638).

No fundo é um atalho para importar/herdar de um prototype já existente.
O código fonte é:

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

Ou seja:

```
FireDetector.super_ = EventEmitter
FireDetector.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: FireDetector,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
});
```